# RSS Feed to one line horizontaly autoscroll textview

Tags: android, rss, textview

In my project I use this library https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library to get rss feed and parse to string  and  this is my  textview xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/rssFeedAutoScrollText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="1000000"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and this a translation animation

```
scrollingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rssFeedAutoScrollText);
        String feed = "";
        try {
            feed = feedTask.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        }

        Log.d("feed", feed);
        String rss = feed.replaceAll(
                "\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", "");
        scrollingTextView.setText(rss);

        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        TranslateAnimation m_ta = new TranslateAnimation(dm.widthPixels, -1
                * (dm.widthPixels), 0f, 0f);
        m_ta.setDuration(20000);
        m_ta.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        m_ta.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

        scrollingTextView.startAnimation(m_ta);
```

but when I'm compile my project textview don't show all symbols of feed string. What is my problem?

Comment: Excuse me, but what do you mean "don't all feed"?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your animation only translates the TextView by the device's width (dm.widthPixels) and not the actual width of the RSS feed string.

For example, if your screen is 600 pixels wide and if the RSS feed string takes more than 600 pixels to display, you will not be able to see the end of your RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

Try following properties for TextView:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="-1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

EDIT: without TranslateAnimation, TextView has builtin text scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

TextView has been replaced to TextSwitcher